# Is there a way to make base exception class not print it's message

Tags: c#, exception, console-application, throw, custom-errors

I'm writing a little program in C#, and in that program i have a base error class that inherits from the `System.Exception` class. Which looks as follows

```
// Simple Error class, used for inheriting to other types of errors
public class Error : Exception {
    public Error(string ErrorType, string ErrorValue) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine($"[{ErrorType}]");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{ErrorValue}");
    }
}
```

the thing is, i'm inheriting from the base `Exception` class so i can `throw` the object. When ***throwing*** it does as it's supposed to. The only thing i wonder is; If there is a way to make the exception part not print itself. I.e the one that shows up since a "Exception was thrown"

`Unhandled Exception: <program-name>.Error: Exception of type '<program-name>.Error' was thrown.`

Comment: Why on God's green Earth would you want an unhandled exception to _not_ be printed? You want the exception to be suppressed and the program to either crash magnificently with no explanation or to chug along merrily in a broken and undefined state?

Comment: since this is just a smal play-thing of a program. I would like to simply just have these custom error messages show up due to "in-execution-program-running-errors". I know that it sound extremely ridiculous but so is this little project as well.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to throw exceptions? and are you sure you actually need custom exceptions for this?

Comment: Exceptions don't print themselves. The .NET runtime is responsible for handling (and printing) exceptions that aren't handled by the program itself. Short of rewriting that part of .NET and recompiling the entire runtime yourself, this is not possible.

Comment: And I also question your use for exceptions for this. Exceptions are meant to showcase a glaring error in your code capable of bringing your program to its knees. Designing your program around the concept of using exceptions as flow control is the definition of an anti-pattern, regardless of the scope of your program.

Comment: @Abion47 Ok! thanks for the answer! i just thought the convenience of being able to `throw` the error was handy. But from what you said, i should just find another way.

Comment: You can delete it if you want. I'd suggest maybe leaving it up for another few hours or so just to see if someone else has alternative suggestions.